# How to implement Highchart in AngularJS.i was trouble with implementation highchart in angular

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bubble-chart

How to implement this code in AngularJS ?

It was not working properly in AngularJS files

http://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/qkr4dqe3/

How to implement Highchart in AngularJS ?

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    zoomType: 'xy'
},

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts bubbles with radial gradient fill'
},

xAxis: {
    type:'',
    gridLineWidth: 1
},

yAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false
},

series: [{
    data: [
        [9, 81, 63],
        [98, 5, 89],
        [51, 50, 73],
        [41, 22, 14],
        [58, 24, 20],
        [78, 37, 34],
        [55, 56, 53],
        [18, 45, 70],
        [42, 44, 28],
        [3, 52, 59],
        [31, 18, 97],
        [79, 91, 63],
        [93, 23, 23],
        [44, 83, 22]
    ],
    marker: {
        fillColor: {
            radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.5).get('rgba')]
            ]
        }
    }
}, ]

});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear , you put a working fiddle and a broken fiddle with a chart property missing. You do not display your Angular implementation.

Comment: i have know exactly answer but when i was implemented in angularjs file the output is below the link  [http://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/7kLkh7ya/4/]

Comment: So you should share your angular implementation for people to provide you with an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you provide in both fiddles it looks like in `xAxis` property you are missing `'category'`:

```
xAxis: {
        type: "category", // <==== here
        gridLineWidth: 1
    }
```

here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javiros/nxg1rav3/)

Comment: Sure check the fiddle I put in the answer. _It works_.

Comment: i know its working i have answer above link  when i was implemented in my project it will comes like below link.Thanks